# Custom partitioner in SPARK (pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a custom partitioner in a spark job using PySpark, say, I have of list of some integers **[10,20,30,40,50,10,20,35]**. Now I want a scenario where I have two partitions say **p1** and **p2**. **p1** contains all the list elements < 30 and **p2** contains all the elements above 30.

```
elements = sc.parallelize([10,20,30,40,50,10,20,35]).map(lambda x : (float(x)/10,x)).partitionBy(2).glom().collect()
```

The above code partitions the list according to the **hash** of the arbitrary key I am passing. Is there anyway of partitioning the list according to a particular scenario ? Like the value is less than x or anything like that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First map your entries with key as themselves like ( (10,10), (20,20))  to get tupled key-value pair. Then use custom partitioner which will decide based on key value to which partition element  is going.

Try implement such class in python:

```
class ExactPartitioner[V](partitions: Int, elements: Int) extends Partitioner {
  def getPartition(key: Any): Int = {
    val k = key.asInstanceOf[Int]
    //0 and 1 are partition number
    return ( k < 30 )? 0 : 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Piggybacking off of FaigB's answer, you want to partition on if the value is above a threshold, not the value itself. Here's how it'd look in python

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([10,20,30,40,50,10,20,35]).map(lambda x : (float(x)/10, float(x)/10))
elements = rdd.partitionBy(2,lambda x: int(x > 3)).map(lambda x: x[0]).glom().collect()
elements
```

Which results in

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0], [4.0, 5.0, 3.5]]
```